# Failed Logic in project

Tags: java

The purpose of the project is to gather user input and output certain prices based on your input. When entering data, it seems as if none of my logic is working and it is returning 0 for a value.

PS. The problem that is wrong is the total price of the cell phone plan. When i call my methods from the main method everything runs but I am assuming my equations aren't correct.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // gathers user input

public class Exam2Hassan {

   public static void main(String [] args) {
         
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);   
  
      int numOfPhones = 0, choice = 0; 
      double finalCost = 0, basePrice = 0, cellPlanCost = 0;
      char goAgain;
      
      
      // holds menu selection
        final int MENU_OPTION_ONE = 1;
        final int MENU_OPTION_TWO = 2;
        final int MENU_OPTION_THREE = 3;
        final int MENU_OPTION_FOUR = 4;

      // calls all methods
      displayData();
      basePrice = basePricing(choice);
      cellPlanCost = calculateCost(numOfPhones, basePrice);  
      finalCost = displayFinalCost(cellPlanCost);
      

   } // end main
   
   
   
   
   
   /**
   This method displays the data plan menu, should not accept any arguments or return any value
   */
   public static void displayData() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // allows user input
        int choice, numOfPhones;
        double cellPlanCost = 0;
        double totalCost = 0;
        char goAgain;
        
        System.out.print("Data Plan Menu: ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t1. 1 GB");
        System.out.println("\t2. 2 GB");
        System.out.println("\t3. 3 GB");
        System.out.println("\t4. 4 GB");
        
        System.out.println();
         
         do { // allows user to input how many plans they want to process
         System.out.print("Select a plan from the menu above: ");
         choice = keyboard.nextInt();
      
         while(choice < 1 || choice > 4)//validate the user's input
         {
            System.out.print("Selection must be between 1 and 4.  Select a plan from the menu above: ");
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
         }
      
         System.out.print("Enter the number of phones: ");
         numOfPhones = keyboard.nextInt();
      
         while(numOfPhones < 1) //validate the user's input
         {
            System.out.print("Number of phones must be at least 1.  Enter the Number of phones: ");
            numOfPhones = keyboard.nextInt();
         }
         
         System.out.printf("The total price of the cell phone plan (before tax and fees) is: $%.2f\n", totalCost);
                
         System.out.println();
         keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.print("Do you wish to calculate the price of another plan (Y/N)? ");
         goAgain = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
         
         System.out.println();
      }
      while(goAgain == 'Y' || goAgain == 'y');
      }
         
   /**
   This method accepts the menu selection as an argument and shows which data plan was selected. should return base pricing   
   */
   public static double basePricing(int choice){        
        
        final double ONE_GB = 34.99;
        final double TWO_GB = 49.99;
        final double FOUR_GB = 64.99;
        final double UNLIMITED_GB = 74.99;
        double basePrice = 0;

                
      
      if(choice == 1) {
         basePrice = 34.99;
      }   
      else if(choice == 2) {
         basePrice = 49.99;
      }
      else if(choice == 3) {
         basePrice = 64.99;
      }
      else if(choice == 4) {
         basePrice = 74.99;

      }
         return basePrice;
      }

   /**
   This method calculates the cost of a cell plan. Accepts number of lines and base pricing. returns the cost of the plan
   */
   public static double calculateCost(int numOfPhones, double basePrice) {
      double cellPlanCost = 0;
      cellPlanCost = basePrice + (10.00 * numOfPhones);
      return cellPlanCost;
       
   }

   /**
   This method should display the final cost. accepts the final cost as argument
   */
    public static double displayFinalCost(double cellPlanCost) {
      
      return cellPlanCost;
    }  
  

} // end class
```

Comment: Your logic flow is quite wrong. You are calling displayData first, the choice should be passed from displayData to basePricing() , on the basis of that, you should call calculateCost and then eventually display the result.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after entering the **number of phones** , there are no logic to calculate cost before printing.

I would suggest you to call following methods after entering **number of phones** inside the `displayData()` method and use finalCost or appropriate variable based on your requirement.

```
basePrice = basePricing(choice);
cellPlanCost = calculateCost(numOfPhones, basePrice);  
finalCost = displayFinalCost(cellPlanCost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for the same.

```
 import java.util.Scanner; // gathers user input

 public class Exam2Hassan {

  public static void main(String [] args) {
     
  // calls all methods
   displayData();

 } // end main
  
 /**
  This method displays the data plan menu, should not accept any arguments or return 
 any value
 */
 public static void displayData() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // allows user input
    int choice, numOfPhones;
    double cellPlanCost = 0;
    double basePrice=0;
    char goAgain;
    
    System.out.print("Data Plan Menu: ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\t1. 1 GB");
    System.out.println("\t2. 2 GB");
    System.out.println("\t3. 3 GB");
    System.out.println("\t4. 4 GB");
    
    System.out.println();
     
     do { // allows user to input how many plans they want to process
     System.out.print("Select a plan from the menu above: ");
     choice = keyboard.nextInt();
     
     while(choice < 1 || choice > 4)//validate the user's input
     {
        System.out.print("Selection must be between 1 and 4.  Select a plan from the menu above: ");
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();
     }
     basePrice=basePricing(choice);
  
     System.out.print("Enter the number of phones: ");
     numOfPhones = keyboard.nextInt();
  
     while(numOfPhones < 1) //validate the user's input
     {
        System.out.print("Number of phones must be at least 1.  Enter the Number of phones: ");
        numOfPhones = keyboard.nextInt();
     }
     cellPlanCost = calculateCost(numOfPhones, basePrice); 
     System.out.printf("The total price of the cell phone plan (before tax and fees) is: $%.2f\n", cellPlanCost);
            
     System.out.println();
     keyboard.nextLine();
     System.out.println();
     System.out.print("Do you wish to calculate the price of another plan (Y/N)? ");
     goAgain = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
     
     System.out.println();
  }
  while(goAgain == 'Y' || goAgain == 'y');
  }
     
 /**
 This method accepts the menu selection as an argument and shows which data plan was 
 selected. should return base pricing   
 */
 public static double basePricing(int choice){        
    
    double basePrice = 0;
  if(choice == 1) {
     basePrice = 34.99;
  }   
  else if(choice == 2) {
     basePrice = 49.99;
  }
  else if(choice == 3) {
     basePrice = 64.99;
  }
  else if(choice == 4) {
     basePrice = 74.99;

  }
     return basePrice;
  }

 /**
  This method calculates the cost of a cell plan. Accepts number of lines and base 
 pricing. returns the cost of the plan
 */
 public static double calculateCost(int numOfPhones, double basePrice) {
  double cellPlanCost = 0;
  cellPlanCost = basePrice + (10.00 * numOfPhones);
  return cellPlanCost;
   
 }

 /**
  This method should display the final cost. accepts the final cost as argument
  */
  public static double displayFinalCost(double cellPlanCost) {
  
  return cellPlanCost;
  }  


 } // end class
```